# How are Neutron namespaced networks connected to the physical interface?

Tags: networking, openstack

Openstack is using namespaces to isolate each network created by 'neutron net-create'.
Since namespaces are isolated from each other but also from the main non-namespaced area, how they end up being connected to the physical interfaces which reside in this "non-namespace" main area?
Which Linux techniques are used for that?

Answer (score 0):

As to what I have seen in the environment I worked on, these interfaces are attached to a virtual bridge in you machine, which is linked also to your physical interfaces.

Comment: Yes, but with Linux network namespaces if you do 'ifconfig' without the 'ip netns exec <namespace_id>' prefix you will not see these virtual interfaces, only the physical interfaces. So the question is how they end up being connected, in the presence of namespaces

Comment: Because these interfaces are linked to your bridge, then they are put in the proper namespace through the `ip link set INTERFACE netns NAMESPACE_ID` command.

Answer (score 0):

libvirt creates the interface and it's name should be visible in the kvm / qemu extended process name.  it should also be query capable via libvirt.